# In English, is there an established prefix for "mostly"?

Tags: prefixes

For half, I could use *semi*, *demi*, or *hemi*.  While *semi* does mean "half", it sometimes has a connotation of "some".  *Demi* is often found with French roots.  According to [this link](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/semi-demi-and-hemi/), *hemi* is the least often used of the three but can also mean "half".

On the other hand, I could use something like *toti* or perhaps other choices to indicate all.

Pardon my mathematical nature, but is there a prefix which would mean "mostly", that is more than one half but less than the full unit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Depending on context *quasi* could work. *Quasi* as a prefix indicates similarity or resemblance. If a sphere is a ball and a hemisphere is half a ball, *quasi-sphere* would mean something that's ball-like, "roughly" or "more or less" a ball.

Comment: Ok, I think will take quasi as a good enough even though not optimal solution.  I am going to count on putting quasi and semi next to each other and the observer being able to detect that quasi > semi in nature.  In this case,  semi carries more the "somewhat" or "sort of" meaning as discussed by @Jon Hanna.

Answer (score 4):

> While semi does mean "half", it sometimes has a connotation of "some".

I'm not convinced by this. It's sometimes used informally to mean "somewhat" or "sort of", but to mean "some" would be rare.

We have *quasi-* for "almost", but not for "most of". It's appropriate when something bears a resemblance to another thing, rather than when it is an incomplete example of something.

We don't have *toti-* as a common prefix, but we do have *pan-* for all of, which is used productively.

Answer (score 3):

[pene](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pene-#Prefix)-, a Latin root, meaning almost, such as in the word [penultimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penultimate)

Although I'm rather sure pene- is prefix you want, here are a few other prefixes that are close in meaning, including some Greek if you were preferring a Greek root.

[mero](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mero-#Prefix)-, a Greek root, meaning partial
[plesio](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plesio-#prefix)-, a Greek root, meaning near
[sub](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sub-#Prefix)-, a Latin root, meaning under
[semi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semi-#Prefix)-, a Latin root, meaning, partial, half

Answer (score 1):

I'd use *[omni-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omni-#Prefix)* or *[multi-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multi-#Prefix)*.  While *omni-* indeed means *all*, it often is appropriated for use as *mostly*, as for example so-called [omnidirectional](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omnidirectional) microphones and antennae are not indeed omnidirectional, but instead most-directions–directional.  *Multi-*, on the other hand, is less of a stretch, as it denotes  “Resembling, pertaining to many or many things”.